# updating database row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a DB with a unique number and a badge number. the badge number will change but the unique number wont.

```
|unique_number|badge_number|
|-------------|------------|
|1234         |2           |
|-------------|------------|
```

I want to be able to update `badge_number` in relation to `unique_number` without creating a new row (un-checking the key "unique"). But currently I get the error `Error: Duplicate entry '1234' for key 'unique_number'`

if I post this code:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table (unique_number, badge_number) VALUES ('1234', 1)";
```

---

## I have tried this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO push (unique_number) VALUES ('".$_POST['unique_number']."')";

$sql2="UPDATE table set badge_number= 0 where unique_number=".$_POST['unique_number']."";

  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo'Error: ' . mysqli_error($con);
  }
  
  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2))
  {
  die('Error2: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
```

Comment: you can use update query.

Comment: could you post an example of the desired result ?

Comment: you can use replace -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a primary key or a unique constraint applied to a column, any insertion of new data must verify the uniqueness of data based on that column. So I guess you have a constraint applied to the `unique_number`Column.

But you still change Data of an exesting row if and only if you the new data verify existing data.

```
UPDATE table SET badge_number = 1 WHERE unique_number = '1234'
```

Comment: Is this still a `mysqli_query` ?

Answer (score 2):

INSERT queries are responsible to insert new records in table.
Hence if you are trying to insert a new row with unique_number=1234, it is violating unique key constraint and generates error Error: Duplicate entry '1234' for key 'unique_number' as there is already a record with this unique_number=1234.

If you want to update the existing record, you can use update query to update any record.
So if you need to update record where unique_number=1234, you need to use following query:

UPDATE table_name SET badge_number = 3 WHERE unique_number = 1234

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following?

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET badge_number = '0' WHERE unique_number = '$_POST['unique_number']'";
```